# how to store text box value in table in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, controllers, model, forms

I need to save form data in table . I need to know better way. Is it better to store from controller. i have tried using following code but no success

form

```
<form id="orderapproval-item-form" class="orderapproval-hidden" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('orderapproval/customercart/remarksdecline');?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="message" class="orderapproval-disabled" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter decline reason'); ?>" id="decline" />
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Decline'); ?>" onclick="namet()" />
```

controller

```
public function remarksdeclineAction()
{
   $message =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');
   $model =Mage::getModel('orderapproval/sales_flat_quote_item');
   $model->setItemcomment( $message );
   $model->save(); // save data

}
```

Model/Orderapproval.php

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_OrderApproval extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
        public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_flat_quote_item');
    }
}
```

Model/Resource/Orderapproval.php

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource_OrderApproval extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
        public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_flat_quote_item', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

Model/Resource/Orderapproval/Collection.php

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource_OrderApproval_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
        protected function _constuct(){
 $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_flat_quote_item'); 
 }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <ZetaPrints_OrderApproval>
      <version>3</version>
    </ZetaPrints_OrderApproval>
  </modules>

  <global>
    <models>
      <orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>zetaprints_orderapproval_resource</resourceModel>
      </orderapproval>

      <ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_resource>
         <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource</class>
         <entities>
             <sales_flat_quote_item>
               <table>sales_flat_quote_item</table>
             </sales_flat_quote_item>
          </entities>
    </ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_resource>

      <sales>
        <rewrite>
          <quote>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Quote</quote>
        </rewrite>
      </sales>
    </models>

    <blocks>
      <orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Block</class>
      </orderapproval>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
      <orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Helper</class>
      </orderapproval>
    </helpers>

    <resources>
      <orderapproval_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval</module>
          <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>Core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </orderapproval_setup>

      <orderapproval_write>
        <connection><use>Core_write</use></connection>
      </orderapproval_write>

      <orderapproval_read>
        <connection><use>Core_read</use></connection>
      </orderapproval_read>
    </resources>
```

setup file for table

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/flat_item')}` 
ADD `itemcomment` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;

");
$installer->endSetup();
```

its my folder name and file name of model folder

```
**

ZetaPrints/OrderApproval/Model/Orderapproval.php
**

ZetaPrints/OrderApproval/Model/Resource/Orderapproval.php
ZetaPrints/OrderApproval/Model/Resource/Orderapproval/Connection.php
```

i have updated my question any one can reply me

Comment: anyone can help me. last two week i am searching for this question someone replied but i did not get solution.

Comment: can you share your table fields? Have your create via script or not?

Comment: no i have created manually not from script

Answer (score 2):

Make changes in your `Model/Orderapproval.php` file:

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_OrderApproval extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_quote_item_order'); //remove item_id from here as it is already defined in your Model/Resource/Orderapproval.php file. Make sure this 'item_id is primary key of your table.
    }
}
```

Then in your controller file make changes as below:

```
public function remarksdeclineAction()
{
   $message =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');
   $model =Mage::getModel('orderapproval/sales_quote_item_order');
   $model->setItemId($item_id); //set your item_id to add the comment in particular row.
   $model->setItemcomment( $message );
   $model->save(); // save data
}
```

Also make sure that the name of the field in table is `itemcomment` and not `item_comment`, because in second case you need to save like this `$model->setItemComment()`

Comment: column name is itemcomment

Comment: dude thanks for your reply but i am getting ...Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setItemId() on boolean

Comment: ok can you share the setup file from which you have created the table ?
I read in your comment that you have created it manually. Then what is the name of your primary key id in that table ?
it should be item_id

Comment: <?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/quote_item')}` 
ADD `itemcomment` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
  


");
$installer->endSetup();

Comment: dude setup file  i have updated in my question

Comment: This will create the field in `sales_flat_quote_item` not in your `sales_quote_item_order` table.

Comment: now i have changed ...<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/flat_item')}` 
ADD `itemcomment` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
  


");
$installer->endSetup();

Comment: i have updated once again please check dude

Comment: you should add like this `$installer->run(" ALTER TABLE {$installer->getTable('sales_quote_item_order')} ADD itemcomment VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL; "); `

Comment: also share me the table structure

Comment: dude table name is sales_flat_quote_item i have updated every in my file but i am still getting same error

Comment: its magento default table i have created a column in this table column name is itemcomment.

Comment: when product add to cart than all product informations are save in this table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51066/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-nirmal-raval).